# Jenkins not sending email "Got bad greeting from SMTP host"

Tags: email, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, smtp, pipeline

I am trying to send an email from a Jenkins pipeline but I am getting the following error

```
Adding recipients from trigger recipient list
Successfully created MimeMessage
Sending email to: 1211732@isep.ipp.pt
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect returning false, host=smtp.gmail.com, user=p-bri, password=<null>
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL false
DEBUG SMTP: EOF: [EOF]
DEBUG SMTP: got bad greeting from host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 465, response: [EOF]
MessagingException message: Got bad greeting from SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: [EOF]
```

I configured the SMTP with the following configurations
[image]

[image]

[image]

This is how I am sending the email

```
 stage('Send confirmation email') {
                emailext(
                        subject: "Pipeline notify - BUILD: '${env.JOB_NAME}#${env.BUILD_NUMBER}'",
                        body: """The pipeline runned successfully. The following tasks have been made:
                        - Project built
                        -Javadoc generation and publish
                        -Runned integration and mutation tests and published its respective reports
                        -Deployed the project to Tomcat, running at http://localhost:8888
                        Build can be found at: ${env.BUILD_URL}""",
                        recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider']],
                        to: "1211732@isep.ipp.pt"
                )                
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Select SSL instead of TLS and  configure the port as 465.

[image]

Test your configure before you save and exit the page.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following settings. This has worked for me.

[image]